# array from ajax success put data into respective input in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In my project i have an ajax request the select entry from database the data that i select is the area and floor number of building it is formatted like this

```
"storey": [{
    "storeyno": "1st Floor",
    "areastorey": "1"
}, {
    "storeyno": "2nd Floor",
    "areastorey": "2"
}, {
    "storeyno": "3rd Floor",
    "areastorey": "3"
}, {
    "storeyno": "4th Floor",
    "areastorey": "4"
}, {
    "storeyno": "5th Floor",
    "areastorey": "5"
}, {
    "storeyno": "6th Floor",
    "areastorey": "6"
}],
```

the two data combination is the row of each table. `Storeyno` represents floor number and it is only a `p` , the `areastoery` is the an input value, it is  the area of the storey.

My question is how to put it back again in the input text.The floor number is not problem ( `storeyno` ) because i am generating it dynamically, the problem is putting the input value.

```
for (var j = 0; j < storeyno.length; j++) {
    console.log(storeyno);
    var bldgstorey = $('table#floor').find('tr:not(:first-child,:last-child)');
    if (storeyno[j].storeyno !== null) {
        bldgstorey.each(function() {
            var floornumber = $(this).find('td p').text();
            var floorinput = $(this).find('td input[type=text]').attr('id');
            console.log(storeyno[j].areastorey + " = " + floorinput);
            console.log(floorinput);
            $(this).find('td input[type=text]').val(storeyno[j].areastorey);
            //$(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').find('input[type=text]').val(storeyno[j].areastorey);
        });
    }
}
```

Notice that from the selector i added `tr:not(:first-child,:last-child)` because the first row is the header while the last row is the total.

`FYI`

I generate the row dynamically but it is not relevant to question so i think it is not important

`Update`

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/L8ukjLb3/)**

Updated sample with sample floors as the sample data

**[Sample with exact same floors](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/L8ukjLb3/1/)**

`Problem`

How to properly place the value correctly from database to input. When i say properly `floor 1 input text box will be populated by database that is for floor 1`

Comment: can you please provide Fiddle ?

Comment: give me a minute i will make one

Comment: So what's your problem? I still not getting it.

Comment: so what is issue here . in fiddle code work fine as it shows value in textbox ?

Comment: please not in the sample ajax data it should be up to 6 floor and the value of the first text box should be the value of the third floor meaning the first and second was disregarded if we add 2 more rows here the 5th and 6th input will be blank when we are expecting them to have value. We expect `floor 1 = 1 , floor 2 = 2, etc.`

Comment: @HogRider  check this linke https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/  you can understand what each function do in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code  . use jquery [each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to get data frmm json.

check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/L8ukjLb3/2/)

```
  $.each(storey,function(key,value){
   $('#floor'+(key+1)).val(value.areastorey);
  });
```